# "Yield" braking a while loop run in thread

Tags: python, multithreading, yield

I have two separate functions, both using socket to communicate with a server. One serves only the purpose of keeping the collection alive and the other one collects data received.

e.g.

```
def keep_connection():
    while True:
       #keeps connection by sending signal to the server
       time.sleep(30)

def data_colector():
    while True:
        out = str(s.recv(auth_file.SocketConnectPort)
        var_index = out.find('269=0')
        var_1 = (((out[var_index + 13:var_index + 20]).replace('.', '')).replace('\\', '')).replace('x', '')
        ...
        print(var_1, var_2, var_3)
```

I run them booth simultaneously with *threading* and all works fine,

```
t_1 = threading.Thread(target=data_colector)
t_2 = threading.Thread(target=keep_connection)
t_1.start()
t_2.start()
```

yet when I change the *print* in data_colector() into *yield* it does not work at all.

```
def data_colector():
    print('confirm thread started')
    while True:
        #collects data received and converts it into few variables
        yield var_1, var_2, var_3
```

No error is returned and it seems like the *thread* running *data_colector()* is not even staring.

Is this normal behavior, how can I make data_colector() *yield* variables?

Comment: Can you show the code where you use `data_colector()`? If you're only calling it once you will only get 1 set of vars since that's what yield does.

Comment: To slightly rephrase what @Loocid said, your `while` loop yields an infinite amount of times, but it always yields the same values. What do you think yield does? Maybe that’s the issue.

Comment: no purpose in showing full code, its long af and mainly issues socket to receive data. Then there is some string cutting etc... Im calling it once, yet it is a while True loop so it should return vars every time they are updated. This function works perfectly when run without threading

Comment: @WiktorKisielewski Could you share a small portion of the code? It’s difficult to diagnose a potentially threading-related issue without the threading part of the code. See: [mcve].

Comment: You don't need to show the full code, but you need to show enough to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @WiktorKisielewski Have a read into what yield does, I think you're misunderstanding how it works.

Comment: @Loocid
Here u go

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Here u go

Comment: @MarkMeyer Here u go

Comment: Changing the code to use `yield` makes the `data_colector` function return a generator instead of any actual values. The actual code in the function is never invoked unless you iterate over the generator the function handed back. Since we only see the function and not how you use the returned generator, we don't know for sure what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Yield is a keyword that is used like return, except the function will return a generator.

```
def data_colector():
    print('confirm thread started')
    # collects data received and converts it into few variables
    for (var_1, var_2, var_3) in some_object:
        yield var_1, var_2, var_3

for a, b, c in data_colector()
    print(a, b, c)
```

So you have to use a loop to call the generator. I have a simple example:

```
def func():
    for i in range(3):
        yield i
a = func()
for i in a:
    print(i)
```

the output is:

```
0
1
2
```